# How to properly handle/shut down custom coroutine dispatcher in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider this piece of code:

```
val coroutineDispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8).asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch(coroutineDispatcher) { println("'launch' finished execution") }
    println("This will be printed, but 'runBlocking' will never exit")
}
```

The `main()` function will never exit and the program will hang forever. However, if I use any of the standard dispatchers, such as `Default`, `IO` etc, the program will end once `runBlocking` and `launch` return. If I call `coroutineDispatcher.close()`, the program will also exit as expected.

**My question is:**

What is the proper way of shutting down such dispatcher if the client code does not have access to it? Let's say I have the following function exposed to the client code:

```
private val coroutineDispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8).asCoroutineDispatcher()

suspend fun doStuff(block: () -> Unit) {
    withContext(coroutineDispatcher) {
        block()
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that when client code finishes the program exits successfully? Especially when `doStuff()` is supposed to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose a `dispose/clear` function to the client, which simply cancels/closes your coroutine scope

Comment: But then it puts the burden of managing resources on the client, which I'd like to avoid. Additionally, none of the default dispatchers have to be closed, so I guess there's a different way

Comment: Well, then you could rely on an abstraction. But I think you have to somehow signal to the repo that your consumer is no longer alive